# How to add a reference to Bing Maps in a Windows 8 mobile application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reference, bing-maps

I have been trying to add a Bing Maps reference to my project but I can't find a reference when searching in the reference manage in Visual Studio 2013.I have installed the SDK in the `extensions and updates` window but still not able to get a reference to it.

Can someone tell me if it is a different process in adding Bing MAPS to a mobile application versus a tablet application? , as I have heard from other sources that it is but can't find any guide for it.

Is there a step I may be missing in adding maps to the project?

To clarify I have set the build to x86 and created a maps key which was added to the project.

Comment: Have you installed the [Windows Phone 8 SDK](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk)?  [Here is an example using - Windows Phone 8 JumpStart: Module 14 Location and Maps Demos](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-JumpStart-b3ef6476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Windows Phone 8` primary maps provider is Nokia. If you want to add `Bing Map`, add a referrence to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll`

Comment: This assembly and its Map class have been marked as deprecated for this platform due to the Here-powered Maps control that supports offline among other new features.

Comment: Yup, for this reason it's not included inside `Windows Phone SDK`. But it can be useful when code shared between WP7 and WP8 projects